# Shortcut to go to the search result panel in VSCode

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, visual-studio-code

I use VSCode in Mac system.

I know that we could use `command+shift+F` to search a word in a project. Is there a quick shortcut to go to the search result panel so that we could navigate through the results by up and down?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

I found it. After searching by `command+shift+F`, typing `command+downarrow` sets the focus on the first element found. Then we could use `up arrow` and `down arrow` to navigate.

[image]

Comment: In case others hit this question and @SoftTimur's answer didn't work, my 2 cents would be to search for: `search.action.focusNextSearchResult` in `Open Keyboard Shortcuts` in the Preferences.

Comment: @SoftTimur Thanks, that's exactly what I wanted! Such a simple keyboard shortcut, but with very poor discoverability.

Answer (score 12):

[Key Bindings for Visual Studio Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/keybindings#_search)
says that 
<kbd>F4</kbd> and <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>F4</kbd>
can be used to focus inside the search results:

---

[image]

Comment: I tried, by typing `F4` and `Shift+F4`, we could indeed go through all the search results. But I would prefer a shortcut to move the focus to the search result panel so that we could navigate search results by `up` and `down` arrows.

Comment: I'm not using VSC, so question: Where is the focus after F4?

Comment: After F4, the focus is in the main editing panel of the files where the search result is.

Comment: Try to find something in the key bindings, but I'm not sure it exists (⌘+k and ⌘+s).

Comment: This one is better than CMD+arrows because the focus/cursor stays in the editor, so you can start editing right away. You can just press f4 or shift+f4 repeatedly to navigate the search results.

Answer (score 2):

There is also the `search.action.focusSearchList` command that focuses the search list and then you can go through the results with up/down arrows.
[image]

Comment: Could you include a screenshot of this in action?